# My data of recyclerview loss in scroll down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and set text some textview in it. when I scroll down or my fragment goes to onPause state my data loss.
what can i do?

```
import static com.test.mohammaddvi.snappfood.Adapter.SectionListDataAdapter.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource;
public class RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter.SingleItemInMenuFragment> {

private ArrayList<Food> foodList;
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter(ArrayList<Food> foodList, Context mContext) {
    this.foodList = foodList;
    this.mContext = mContext;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter.SingleItemInMenuFragment onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.foodlist, null);
    return new RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter.SingleItemInMenuFragment(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter.SingleItemInMenuFragment holder, int position) {
    Food food = foodList.get(position);
    holder.foodName.setText(food.getName());
    holder.foodDetails.setText(food.getDetails());
    holder.foodPrice.setText(food.getPrice() + " تومان ");
    holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.foodMinusButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(0 + "");
    holder.foodImage.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(), mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(food.getImage(),
            "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()), 50, 50));
    handleClick(holder, position);
}

private void handleClick(final SingleItemInMenuFragment holder, final int position) {
    holder.foodPlusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int orderNumber = Integer.parseInt(holder.foodOrderNumber.getText().toString());
            holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(orderNumber + 1 + "");
            holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.foodMinusButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    holder.foodMinusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int orderNumber = Integer.parseInt(holder.foodOrderNumber.getText().toString());
            if (orderNumber > 1) {

                holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(orderNumber - 1 + "");
                holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            if (orderNumber == 1) {

                holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(orderNumber - 1 + "");
                holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.foodMinusButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != foodList ? foodList.size() : 0);
}


public class SingleItemInMenuFragment extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView foodName;
    TextView foodPrice;
    Button foodPlusButton;
    Button foodMinusButton;
    TextView foodOrderNumber;
    ImageView foodImage;
    TextView foodDetails;

    SingleItemInMenuFragment(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        this.foodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        this.foodImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageFood);
        this.foodPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodPrice);
        this.foodDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodDetails);
        this.foodPlusButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.plusbutton);
        this.foodMinusButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.minusbutton);
        this.foodOrderNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ordernumber);

    }
}
```

}
and this is my fragment that i use recyclerview in that:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{
private static final String TAG = "menufragment";
ArrayList<Food> allfoods = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerview;
private static Bundle bundle;
private final String KEY_RECYCLER_STATE= "recycler_state";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menufragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String jsonFilePath = "foods.json";
    recyclerview = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lstitems);
    RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter(allfoods, getContext());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    parsJson(jsonFilePath);
}

//this method is for read a local json and return a string
public String readLocalJson(String jsonFile) {
    String json;
    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open(jsonFile);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

public void parsJson(String jsonFilePath) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(readLocalJson(jsonFilePath));
        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
            JSONArray jsonArrayFoot = jsonObject.getJSONArray("foots");
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayFoot.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectFoot = jsonArrayFoot.getJSONObject(j);
                String foodName = jsonObjectFoot.getString("name");
                String fooddetails = jsonObjectFoot.getString("fooddetails");
                String price = jsonObjectFoot.getString("price");
                allfoods.add(new Food(foodName, price, fooddetails, image));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code for better help

Comment: @veritas1 i add my recyclerview adapter

Comment: move parsJson(jsonFilePath) before your adapter constructor or call adapter's notifyDataSetChanged after  parsJson(jsonFilePath)

Comment: @Mosius my problem is still on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just initialized the data on `onStart` which will eventually called when your activity/fragment is resumed, and because of that all data you've changed was overwritten to initial data.

Move your `onStart` initialization to `onViewCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated() {
    super.onViewCreated();
    String jsonFilePath = "foods.json";
    recyclerview = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lstitems);
    RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter(allfoods, getContext());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    parsJson(jsonFilePath);
}
```

And for scrolling, its normal because RecyclerView recycles the view from the list above but the data is not, so what you need to do is store values from the list source.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewMenuFragmentAdapter.SingleItemInMenuFragment holder, int position) {
    Food food = foodList.get(position);
    holder.foodName.setText(food.getName());
    holder.foodDetails.setText(food.getDetails());
    holder.foodPrice.setText(food.getPrice() + " تومان ");
    holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.foodMinusButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(food.getFoodOrderNumber());
    holder.foodImage.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(), mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(food.getImage(),
            "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()), 50, 50));
    handleClick(holder, position);
}

private void handleClick(final SingleItemInMenuFragment holder, final int position) {
    holder.foodPlusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int orderNumber = Integer.parseInt(holder.foodOrderNumber.getText().toString());
            int newOrderNumber = orderNumber + 1;
            Food food = foodList.get(position);
            food.setFoodOrderNumber(newOrderNumber);
            holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(newOrderNumber + "");
            holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.foodMinusButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    holder.foodMinusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Food food = foodList.get(position);

            int orderNumber = food.getFoodOrderNumber();
            if (orderNumber > 1) {
                int newOrderNumber = orderNumber - 1;
                food.setFoodOrderNumber(newOrderNumber);
                holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(newOrderNumber + "");
                holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            if (orderNumber == 1) {
                int newOrderNumber = orderNumber - 1;
                food.setFoodOrderNumber(newOrderNumber);
                holder.foodOrderNumber.setText(newOrderNumber + "");
                holder.foodOrderNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.foodMinusButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

And on your `Food` object just add this field and functions:

```
public class Food {
    int foodOrderNumber;

    public int getFoodOrderNumber() {
        return foodOrderNumber;
    }

    public void setFoodOrderNumber(int foodOrderNumber) {
        this.foodOrderNumber = foodOrderNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this line to your onBindViewHolder method and check again if the problem still exits:

```
 holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Comment: I added and the problem still exists